# maven clearcase integration analysis

Tags: maven-2, maven, clearcase

I am planning to integrate Clearcase UCM(under dynamic view) with Maven.

> 1) I found that Maven SCM is partially
>   implemented for clearcase. Is there
>   are any still issue with this? what is
>   meaning partailly implemented SCM?
>
> 2) How compatable Clearcase with
>   Maven?
>
> 3)Any issues or limitation with this 2
>   tools integration?
>
> 4)Maven docs says that it is not
>   possible to use SCM plugin features
>   like creating tags (applying labels),
>   creating Change logs, and so on.
>
> 5) where can i find good document to integrate Maven with clearcase?. Apache site have given, but it is not very clear for beginners.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298228/maven-hudson-and-dynamic-clearcase-views as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few documentations on Maven with UCM ClearCase, and limitations like the ones described in [SCM Implementation: ClearCase](http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html):

> The ClearCase SCM provider uses snapshot views.

(so no dynamic view for instance, but you mention tags, which should be implemented as UCM baseline)

> As no SCM metadata can be accessed, it is not possible to use SCM plugin features like creating tags (applying labels), creating changelogs, and so on.

Another limitation, in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14569643):

> Hi. I have been able to integrate Hudson and ClearCase without too much trouble using a Windows machine. Downloading source code from a given baseline or stream is fine.
>
> The problem comes if you try to use some ant tasks for checking out a pom file, make some changes ( like updating some version numbers ) and then checkin the modified pom file before starting to build.
>
> No matter if I use an ant script with ClearCase tasks, or internal Java classes, or even a maven-release-plugin for Hudson that tries to do this kind of job, I always end with the following error :

```
cleartool: Error: Type manager "_xml2" failed create_version operation
```

> when trying to checking a XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of integration are you looking for?
If it's about identifying and documenting the changes between UCM baselines, streams, activities and components, you can use [CompBL](http://gomidjets.com/compbl) - a complemntary add-on for ClearCase.
It's an easy to install add-on yet very powerful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is an error thrown by clearcase while checking in xml files, if xml file is exceeding more then /1000 characters.
try changing xml file type, this will resolve the issue "cleartool chtype file file.xml"